# 404 pages and Lazy Loading in Angular2

Tags: angular, routes, http-status-code-404

I am unable to let my '404 pages' work using lazy loading modules. When I enter a random url in the browser I only see a blank page instead of my cool 404 page.

Here is my routing config

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'},
  { path: 'buckets', loadChildren: 'app/buckets/buckets.module#BucketsModule'},
  { path: '**', loadChildren: 'app/notfound/notfound.module#NotFoundModule'} 
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

When I surf to /buckets I see the chunk is being lazy loaded and it shows the appropriate component which is configured in the Buckets Module, thats ok.

But it doesn't work with 404 error pages. Normally '**' for path should work for all other unexistent routes, but it doesn't.

Can someone help?

-angular2 final (2.0.0)

Answer (score 7):

URL matching wont work with wildcard lazy loaded modules. I wonder what you will add in the routing inside your Lazy loaded modules.

Having said that you may try to redirect to a different route for wildcard routes like below,

```
{ path: 'notfound', loadChildren: 'app/notfound/notfound.module#NotFoundModule'}
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/notfound' }
```

**Update**

you may give an empty path in Module routing so that it loads default component,

```
const notfoundRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

This makes sure that when you route to a path which is not configured it goes and loads NotFound module lazily.

See this [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wqs20ufxiMHEYFhywguF?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: @webmaster: it works check the Plunker updated in solution,  i see that the route is not properly configured in the solution you have added hence you have to import the Module. Cheers!!

Comment: Well done Madhu, I was struggling with this for hours and your solution works! This is the only way to Lazy Load a 404 error page that I can see...  (this should be marked as the correct answer)

Comment: "URL matching won't work with wildcard lazy loaded modules." - it will work, it's just the case that given wildcard matches all URLs.

Having said that, any URL will make the lazyloaded module to load, so it's not a real 'lazy loaded' module anymore. It's just a chunk of application that is kept and loaded from separate chunk file on application load.

But the proposed solution seems solid.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out, what I did was the following.

imported the NotFound module in AppModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    NotFoundModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

inside the NotFound module I declared a route (not a lazy one)

```
const routes: Routes =  [
  { 
    path: 'notfound', 
    component: NotFoundComponent
  }
]
```

in the AppModule routings I added

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'},
  { path: 'buckets', loadChildren: 'app/buckets/buckets.module#BucketsModule'},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/notfound' } 
];
```

This way the NotFound module is directly imported in the app, so it does exist in the application context.

Everytime you enter a unexistent route you get routed to /notfound ;)

Comment: Hmm - I had this working already but am trying to move the 404 page to LazyLoading (it will only be hit 1% of the time so I don't want to bundle it up front like this). I cannot get it to work with Lazy Loading...